# Does this matrix involving roots of unity has a particular name?

Tags: matrices, algebraic-number-theory, roots-of-unity

Do the matrices of the form $\left(\begin{matrix} \frac{\xi + \xi^{-1}}{2} & \frac{\xi - \xi^{-1}}{2} \\ \frac{\xi - \xi^{-1}}{2} & \frac{\xi + \xi^{-1}}{2} \end{matrix}\right)$ where $\xi$ is a root of unity has a particular name?

Those matrices are popping up in something I am working with and I am wondering if they have a particular name. (I am interested in things like their order and stuff.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\xi=e^{i\theta}$, then your matrix is
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos\theta&i\sin\theta\\i\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{array}\right).
$$
This is similar to the matrix representing a plane rotation - conjugated by $diag(1,i)$. This time the eigenvectors are $(1,\pm1)^T$ instead of the usual $(1,\pm i)^T$.
The eigenvalues are $e^{\pm i\theta}$ anyway.

If $\theta=2\pi k/n$ with $\gcd(k,n)=1$ this matrix is of order $n$.

Comment: You can also write it as $I\cos \theta + J\sin \theta$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. $J^2 = -I$. $J$ is like the complex number $i$.